# Converting a number in javascript to a 4 byte array

Tags: c#, javascript, node.js, network-programming

I'm taking my shot at writing a node server in which I need to send a 32 bit integer to a c# client (as the header).

I'm not quite sure how to do that, as the bit shift operators confuse me.  I think my c# client expects these integers in little endian format (I'm not sure, I say that because the `NetworkStream` IsLittleEndian property is true).

So say I have a variable in javascript that's something like

```
var packetToDeliverInBytes = GetByteArrayOfSomeData();

//get the integer we need to turn into 4 bytes
var sizeOfPacket = packetToDeliver.length;

//this is what I don't know how to do
var bytes = ConvertNumberTo4Bytes(sizeOfPacket)

//then somehow do an operation that combines these two byte arrays together
//(bytes and packetToDeliverInBytes in this example)
//so the resulting byte array would be (packetToLiver.length + 4) bytes in size

//then send the bytes away to the client
socket.write(myByteArray);
```

How do I write the ConvertNumberTo4Bytes() function?

**Bonus**

How do I combine these 2 byte arrays into one so I can send them in one socket.write call

Comment: See if this helps: http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readuint32le_offset_noassert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `Buffer` object in node seems to be the way to go thanks to elclanrs comment.

```
var buf = new Buffer(4 + sizeOfPacket);
buf.writeInt32LE(sizeOfPacket, 0);
buf.write(packetToDeliverInBytes, 4);

socket.write(buf);
```